# Connect react-redux to stateless component. Properties inside the function are not updated

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

**Problem:**

I have very simple todo app. There is one action - add todo. When I add a task, I simulate sending it to the server using a setTimeout.

*When I receive a response from the server, I immediately check to see if there is an error to avoid further action. In stateful component, everything works, and in stateless component it doesn't.*

See the code to better understand the problem.

**Environment:**

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.5",
"react-redux": "^7.1.1",
"redux": "^4.0.4",
"redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
```

**№ 1. Stateful component:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Button, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {addTodo as addTodoAction} from '../redux/reducer';

class MainScreen extends Component {
  todoGenerator = () => ({
    id: new Date().getTime(),
    text: 'Pls help me ' + new Date().getTime(),
  });

  sendTodoToServer = async () => {
    const todo = this.todoGenerator();
    const {addTodo} = this.props;
    await addTodo(todo);

    // this
    const {error} = this.props;
    if (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const {isLoading} = this.props;

    return (
      <View>
        <Button title="Generate todo" onPress={this.sendTodoToServer} />
        {isLoading && <ActivityIndicator />}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    todos: state.todos,
    error: state.error,
    isLoading: state.isLoading,
  }),
  {
    addTodo: addTodoAction,
  },
)(MainScreen);
```

**№ 1. Stateful component. Console:**

As you can see,

```
 const {error} = this.props;
 if (error) {
     console.log('error', error);
 }
```

it's work. Okay, let's move on to functional components

[image]

**№ 2. Stateless component with redux connect:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator, Button, View} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {addTodo as addTodoAction} from '../redux/reducer';

const MainScreenFC = ({isLoading, addTodo, error}) => {
  const todoGenerator = () => ({
    id: new Date().getTime(),
    text: 'Pls help me ' + new Date().getTime(),
  });

  const sendTodoToServer = async () => {
    const todo = todoGenerator();
    await addTodo(todo);

    if (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Generate todo" onPress={sendTodoToServer} />
      {isLoading && <ActivityIndicator />}
    </View>
  );
};

export default connect(
  state => ({
    todos: state.todos,
    error: state.error,
    isLoading: state.isLoading,
  }),
  {
    addTodo: addTodoAction,
  },
)(MainScreenFC);
```

**№ 2. Stateless component with redux connect. Console:**

The error did not display in the console, although it is in the reducer

[image]

**№ 3. Stateless component with redux HOOKS:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator, Button, View} from 'react-native';
import {connect, shallowEqual, useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {addTodo as addTodoAction} from '../redux/reducer';

const MainScreenReduxHooks = () => {
  const todos = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.todos, shallowEqual);
  const error = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.error, shallowEqual);
  const isLoading = useSelector(
    (state: AppState) => state.isLoading,
    shallowEqual,
  );

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const todoGenerator = () => ({
    id: new Date().getTime(),
    text: 'Pls help me ' + new Date().getTime(),
  });

  const sendTodoToServer = async () => {
    const todo = todoGenerator();
    await dispatch(addTodoAction(todo));

    if (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Generate todo" onPress={sendTodoToServer} />
      {isLoading && <ActivityIndicator />}
    </View>
  );
};

export default connect(
  state => ({
    todos: state.todos,
    error: state.error,
    isLoading: state.isLoading,
  }),
  {
    addTodo: addTodoAction,
  },
)(MainScreenReduxHooks);
```

**№ 3. Stateless component with redux HOOKS. Console:**

It's the same here, as in the second example.

**Questions:**

1. Can redux be connected to a stateless component?
2. How do you make the second and third example work the same way as the first?

**Other code:**

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {MainScreen, MainScreenFC, MainScreenReduxHooks} from './src/screens';
import store from './src/redux';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MainScreenFC />
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**store.js:**

```
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import rootReducer from './reducer';

export default createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger));
```

**reducer.js:**

```
const ADD_TODO_REQUEST = 'ADD_TODO_REQUEST';
const ADD_TODO_SUCCESS = 'ADD_TODO_SUCCESS';
const ADD_TODO_FAILURE = 'ADD_TODO_FAILURE';

const initialState = {
  todos: [],
  isLoading: false,
  error: undefined,
};

export const addTodo = data => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: ADD_TODO_REQUEST,
    payload: {
      isLoading: true,
    },
  });

  try {
    const todo = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        reject('Ooops, error');
      }, 3000);
    });

    dispatch({
      type: ADD_TODO_SUCCESS,
      payload: {
        todo,
        isLoading: false,
      },
    });
  } catch (e) {
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_TODO_FAILURE,
      payload: {
        isLoading: false,
        error: e,
      },
    });
  }
};

export default function(state = initialState, {type, payload}) {
  switch (type) {
    case ADD_TODO_REQUEST: {
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    }
    case ADD_TODO_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        todos: [...state.todos, payload.todo],
      };
    }
    case ADD_TODO_FAILURE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        error: payload,
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem with your code is that you try to wait for a response in the component, it's a bad idea for both stateful and stateless components. What would I recommend you to do, is to handle error somewhere in your middleware (`redux-thunk`, `redux-saga`, etc). In this case, your component should just represent data, and if you have to display an error, just take it from props, I believe it is stored somewhere in redux.

In any way, stateless components shouldn't be an async function, because the result of an async function is a promise but not a component. There are some libraries like `async-reactor`, but personally, I prefer to go with another approach.

If you tell me your use case, what would you like to do once you got an error, I'll give you a more useful answer.

**Update:**

```
export const addTodo = data => dispatch => {
  // tell your application that request is sending,
  // so you can handle it in UI (show a progress indicator)
  dispatch({
    type: ADD_TODO_REQUEST,
    payload: data
  });

  try {
    const response = await createTodo(data);

    dispatch({
      type: ADD_TODO_SUCCESS,
      payload: response
    });

    // here you can dispatch navigation action as well

  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_TODO_FAILURE,
      error
    });

    // and here you can dispatch action with a toast
    // to notify users that something went wrong
  }
};
```

Comment: Example. If the task is successfully added to the server, you need to switch to another screen, such as detailed information about the task. If there's a mistake, you can't do anything. Let's say I wrapped this component in a higher-order component where snackbar occurs when the error occurs.

Comment: Since you use Redux it is much better to integrate your routing library with it and dispatch a navigation action once the request was successfully sent or a toast if there was some error.